# Javascript check all toggleclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

i need help to create check all button using javascript, i can to create check button but just one by one
this is my code to check one by one,

```html
<script language="Javascript">
$(".action-check").click(function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        console.log('checklist count : ' +$(".action-check.active").length);
        if($(".action-check.active").length > 0){
          $("#unfavorite").removeClass('btn-disabled disabled').addClass('btn-danger');
        }else{
          $("#unfavorite").addClass('btn-disabled disabled').removeClass('btn-danger');
        }
      });
</script>

<ul class="user-action">
 <li>
<a class="action-check" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="1" data-code="01">
<i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="action-check" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="2" data-code="02">
<i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry, your requirement is not clear - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y8tygddw/1/ - can you tell us what should happen based on the attached fiddle

Comment: Check this update http://jsfiddle.net/y8tygddw/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y8tygddw/6/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is just the styling of the buttons, all you have to do is reset the :hover and :focus state (since these are styled the in the stylesheet).
http://jsfiddle.net/y8tygddw/5/

```
.action-check:hover,
.action-check:focus { color: #428bca; }

.action-check.active {
    color: #2a6496;
}
```